# Rails Sidekiq Worker Won't Execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am attempting to run a cron job on a rails site to execute a daily task in background. I am using Sidekiq to run the job.

It seems like everything is running correctly up to the point that it should execute the "perform" method in the worker, except that none of the code in this method executes. It is added to the queue on schedule and sidekiq logs that the task was run, but nothing happens. I know that the code in the perform method works because I have loaded it into the rails console and run the method there and it does exactly what is expected. It just doesn't do it when Sidekiq runs it.

Output from crontab -l

```
0 1 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/xxxx/yyy && environment_variable=production bundle exec sidekiq-client push ReviewWorker'

0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/xxxx/yyy && environment_variable=production bundle exec sidekiq-client push ReviewWorker'
```

Worker Code

```
class ReviewWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    def perform
        containers = Container.where(display_listing: true, review_trigger_date: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
        containers.each do |container|
            unless container.reviews.size > 0
                review = Review.new(container_id: container.id)
                review.save
                ReviewMailer.initial_review(container).deliver
            end
        end
        containers = Container.where(display_listing: true, review_trigger_date: 7.days.ago.beginning_of_day..7.days.ago.end_of_day)
        containers.each do |container|
            unless container.reviews.size > 1
                review = Review.new(container_id: container.id)
                review.save
                ReviewMailer.followup_review(container).deliver
            end
        end
        containers = Container.where(display_listing: true, review_trigger_date: 14.days.ago.beginning_of_day..14.days.ago.end_of_day)
        containers.update_all(display_listing: false)
    end
end
```

Sidekiq Log

```
2016-01-13T14:55:03.028Z 22748 TID-qvycc ReviewWorker JID-7d1ae22cd06a1e0515de4aef INFO: start
2016-01-13T14:55:03.270Z 22748 TID-qvycc ReviewWorker JID-7d1ae22cd06a1e0515de4aef INFO: done: 0.243 sec
```

Let me know if you need to see anything else to diagnose. I'm not getting any errors or retries. But it doesn't save the review and it doesn't send the mailer. Yet it does when I run it via console. And yes, I have reset the data so it should catch it and confirmed this via console as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with how sidekiq was running. I was running it on the server while testing by simply executing:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

Once I set it up on the server to run as a system service, it worked, though. Part of the command to set it up as a system service was to set the environment to production, so I suspect that that was the problem as the original command didn't do that.

Comment: I would recommend using https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq for deployments to get things started properly.  It also allows you to configured number of processes per server and which server roles you should run sidekiq on.  And it gives you cap sidekiq:restart command line tasks .  And instead of using crontab I like https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron.  Schedule is stored in Redis.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was actually using whenever to set the cron, which seems to work well for my purposes. I haven't messed around with capistrano yet, but seems to be well liked in the community. I will have to check it out.

Comment: whenever is a good gem, I use it for other things in my applications.  I do recommend checking out capistrano or another tool for deployments.  Really simplifies things.